# Dhrystone 2.1 version reviews for calculating MIPS

Tags: arm, benchmarking

I want to know if it's ok to use dhrystone as a benchmark to calculate MIPS, since it is very old. Or should I go for new benchmarks like Coremark?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its better to go for CoreMark I guess, since it can handle processor complexities in a better way. Even ARM recommends this in the below link
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0350a/ar01s02.html

Comment: I agree with Roy that it's usefull mainly for comparisons. Moreover IMO there are many other aspects apart from MIPS which you should consider: floating point operations (whetstone!), memory bandwidth, cache efficiency... Plus can you explain what you mean with "Coremark can handle processor complexities in a better way" ?

Comment: Since the code of Dhrystone is small optimization can be done on Dhrystone to get better results .
By complexities I mean coremark handles integers, state machine,float varibales where as Dhrystone handles only integers.Coremark can be used even on processors without cache.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that a single benchmark can provide a representative MIPS measurement across the board, let alone one that produces a synthetic result that depends on the compiler used. However, it can be useful for broad brush historic comparison, particularly if the same compilations have been run on a range of systems. The following has results for the same code run on PCs (MS SW) from 80386 to Core i7, plus others via Linux or for Androids and Raspberry Pi, that can be used tongue-in-cheek.

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/dhrystone%20results.htm

This also provides a link to my CPUSpeed.htm with a range of MIPS/MHz ratios for different programs, for which the real assembly code instruction count is known for some of them. Typical range of %MIPS/MHz is 52% to 397%.

Comment: opt VAX MIPS and Noopt VAX MIPS. Do these two mean DMIPS. If yes what is the diffrenence between opt and No opt. Please let me know

Comment: Opt means using compiler option to optimise for performance. Benchmark measures Dhrystones per Second. The first 1 MIPS minicomputer was assumed to be the DEC VAX 11/780, rated at 1757 Dhrys/sec. Dividing measured Drys/sec by this gives VAX MIPS that some call DMIPS.